# How can change in Enthalpy for a reaction be written like this?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, ideal-gas

If a gas expands in a container with constant external pressure then:

$W=-P_{ext}\Delta V$

Instead of $P_{ext}$ if we use $P_{int}$ then we will not get the same value because  $P_{int}$ is constantly decreasing from a certain value until equilibrium is attained, while the change in volume remains the same.

This is the reason why we use $P_{ext}$ here:

$\Delta H= \Delta U +P_{ext} \Delta V$

But then, $\Delta H$ for a reaction is:

$\Delta H= \Delta U +\Delta n_{g}RT$ ($n_{g}$ is for change in number of gaseous moles as the solids and liquids are ignored)

where $PV=nRT$ is used. However, the $P$ in the ideal gas equation is $P_{int}$.

So my question is how can $P_{int}$ be substituted in the place of $P_{ext}$ if the values of work done change when we do so?

Comment: Who says the change in enthalpy is $\Delta U+P_{ext}\Delta V$?  Please provide a reference.  This is not correct.

Comment: I've seen $\Delta H=\Delta U +P \Delta V$ in text books and when showing that $\Delta  H=q$ under constant pressure the work from $\Delta U = q+w$ gets canceled out with $P \Delta V$ from $\Delta H$  so I thought that for it to cancel out with work the $P$ had to be $P_{ext}$.Hence, the $\Delta H=\Delta U +P_{ext} \Delta V$

Comment: How would that work for an adiabatic irreversible expansion at constant external pressure (for which q = 0)?

Comment: @ChetMiller I don't see why it woudn't work. Wouldn't $\Delta H=0$ for adiabatic irreversible expansion.

Comment: Does the temperature change?  Is the enthalpy of an ideal gas a function of temperature?

Comment: @ChetMiller Temperature does change, therefore $\Delta H \neq 0$ as $\Delta H$ is a function of temperature for ideal gases. Ok, then what would be the correct expression for change in enthalpy that would work all the time.

Comment: The correct equation is always $$\Delta H=\Delta U+P_fV_f-P_iV_i$$Is the pressure of the gas in the initial thermodynamic equilibrium state of the gas $P_i$ in this irreversible expansion equal to the gas pressure in the final thermodynamic equilibrium state of the gas $P_f=P_{ext}$?

Comment: But the gas pressure in the initial state is not equal to final pressure in the irreversible expansion.  $\Delta H=q$ only for a *reversible* isobaric process (for which the final and initial equilibrium pressures of the gas are the same).

Comment: @ChetMiller yes, $P_f=P_{ext}$.So,$P_f$ and $P_i$ are internal pressures right. Then will we get the expression $\Delta H=q$ for a process at constant pressure?$\Delta U=q+w=q-P_{ext}\Delta V$ and $\Delta H = \Delta U+\Delta (PV)$ at constant external pressure. Substituting $\Delta U$ will we be able to cancel out some terms to get $\Delta H=q$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121076/discussion-between-aditya-bharadwaj-and-chet-miller).

Comment: Only if the initial and final equilibrium pressures are equal, which is only the case if the isobaric process is reversible.  Otherwise, for your case, $\Delta H=-(P_i-P_{ext}) V_i$

Comment: @ChetMiller But, I have seen $\Delta H$ being interchangeable used with heat even when the inital and final equilibrium pressures are not equal .
Like to determine whether a process is spontaneous or not.$\Delta S_{total}=\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr} \geq 0$. here $\Delta S_{surr}=-q/T$ which is written as $-\Delta H/T$ but if a process is spontaneous it certainly isn't reversible.

Comment: For an ideal isothermal reservoir, the fluid in the reservoir is assumed to be incompressible, in which case the changes in enthalpy and internal energy of the reservoir are both equal to the heat received by the reservoir. Which $\Delta H$ does your entropy equation refer to, the enthalpy change of the reservoir or the enthalpy change of the system?

Comment: @ChetMiller The system.

Comment: What was the process that the system experienced?

Comment: @ChetMiller Say for a chemical reaction that takes place under constant temperature and pressure.

Comment: In that case, the initial and final pressures of the system are the same, and equal to the external pressure of the surroundings.  So...?

Comment: Are you asking why the standard change in entropy of a reaction is not equal to the standard change in enthalpy divided by the standard temperature?

Comment: Thanks, I think I have satisfactorily cleared up my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim that $\Delta H = \Delta U + P_{ext} \Delta V$ is incorrect. It is only correct when the system is always in mechanical equilibrium with the external pressure, or in other words irreversible expansion against constant pressure. The more general statement is $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (PV) $. Here as you can see even when you compare it with $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta n_gRT$ there is no problem as we don't have to replace $P_{in} $ with $P_{ext} $.